# PhpStorm Terminal result is different with OS terminal result

Tags: php, terminal, phpstorm

In the macOS terminal when I type `php -v` in the specific folder, it returns:

```
PHP 7.4.12 (cli) (built: Oct 29 2020 18:28:50) ( NTS )
```

But when I run the same command in the same directory in PhpStorm Terminal it returns:

```
PHP 7.1.23 (cli) (built: Feb 22 2019 22:19:32) ( NTS )
```

Anyone can help?

Comment: What's your OS? Most likely the way how you launch your IDE does not put the latest environment for you ... so you may have different `PATH` content and hence the different OS versions. How do you launch it? If you launch IDE from your OS terminal, it will inherit all the stuff. But if you are clicking on the icon (launch bar) it may not read such stuff (e.g. files like `.bashrc` or alike)

Comment: Did you restart PhpStorm after installing your brand-spanking-new php on your mac (I am assuming you used brew). Did you set your PATH environment variable to present the `/usr/local/bin` folder before all others (.bashrc) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems we should open PhpStorm with the main OS Terminal like as this command:

`open -a /Applications/PhpStorm.app/`

Thanks to @lazyOne.

Answer (score 0):

some IDE ship with a compiler/interpreter itself.

you can use their compiler/interpreter or your system compiler/interpreter.

PhpStorm ships with an integrated Php:

> https://www.javatpoint.com/phpstorm

there a lot of such as these Ide`s like:

jupyter with integrated python

android studio with integrated java

this link help you to change the interpreter php:

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/configuring-local-interpreter.html

Comment: How to set it on PhpStorm?

Comment: @Erfan Atp : have you succeed ?

Comment: unfortunately no!

Comment: dosent the link help you out?

Comment: 1) *"PhpStorm ships with an integrated Php:"* It is NOT CORRECT. PhpStorm does NOT come bundled with any PHP stuff -- all PHP related tools (PHP itself, Xdebug extension, Composer etc) you must install yourself. 2) PHP Interpreter has NOTHING to do with what `php -v` will print in your terminal as it is used for launching stuff from IDE only.

Comment: @LazyOne So what should I do?

Comment: @ErfanAtp 1) Try starting PhpStorm from your OS terminal, something like `open -a /Applications/PhpStorm.app/` (adjust as needed)-- any better? 2) If it works now, check these comments (should help): https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000112490/comments/115000143610 and https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000809520-Webstorm-Cordova-integration-?page=1#community_comment_360000141219 . They are about WebStorm and JS related tools, but the overall idea is the same

Comment: @LazyOne It works. When I open the IDE from the terminal, everything works fine. Do you know how to fix it without the OS terminal?

Comment: @ErfanAtp Check my **whole** comment and not just first half only. It has some links showing what possibly can be done (the overall approach). Since I'm not a Mac user myself I cannot provide a more specific ticket. But you are welcome to look through other threads there on JetBrains forums -- just use search and look for Mac specific answers.